# How does this method, which finds the smallest factor of a given number, work?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, factorization

I've recently come across a method which returns the smallest factor of a given number:

```
public static int findFactor(int n) 
{
    int i = 1;

    int j = n - 1;

    int p = j; // invariant: p = i * j

    while(p != n && i < j) 
    {
        i++; 
        p += j;

        while(p > n) 
        {
            j--; 
            p -= i;
        }
    }

    return p == n ? i : n;
}
```

After examining the method, I've been able to (most likely incorrectly) determine the quantities which some of is variables respectively represent:

```
n = the int that is subject to factorization for 
    the purposes of determining its smallest factor

i = the next potential factor of n to be tested

j = the smallest integer which i can be multiplied by to yield a value >= n
```

The problem is I don't know what quantity `p` represents. The inner loop seems to treat `(p+=j) - n` as a
potential multiple of `i`, but given what I believe `j` represents, I don't understand how that can be true
for all `i`, or how the outer loop accounts for the "extra" iteration of the inner loop that is carried out
before the latter terminates as a result of `p < n`

Assuming I've correctly determined what `n`, `i`, and `j` represent, what quantity does `p` represent?

If any of my determinations are incorrect, what do each of the quantities represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p` stands for “product”.  The invariant, as stated, is `p == i*j`; and the algorithm tries different combinations of `i` and `j` until the product (`p`) equals `n`.  If it never does (the `while` loop falls through), you get `p != n`, and hence `n` is returned (`n` is prime).

At the end of the outer `while` loop's body, `j` is the largest integer which `i` can be multiplied by to yield a value ≤ `n`.

The algorithm avoids explicit division, and tries to limit the number of `j` values inspected for each `i`.  At the beginning of the outer loop, `p==i*j` is just less than `n`.  As `i` is gradually increased, `j` needs to gradually shrink. In each outer loop, `i` is increased (and `p` is corrected to match the invariant).  The inner loop then decreases `j` (and corrects `p`) until `p` is ≤ `n` again.  Since `i*j` is *only just* less than `n` at the beginning of the next outer loop, increasing `i` makes the product greater than `n` again, and the process repeats.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm tries all divisors between `1` and `n / i` (continuing past `n / i` is of no use as the corresponding quotients have already been tried).

So the outer loop actually performs

```
i= 1
while i * (n / i) != n && i < n / i)
{
  i++;
}
```

It does it in a clever way, by avoiding divisions. As the annotation says, the invariant `p = i * j` is maintained; more precisely, `p` is the *largest* multiple of `i` that doesn't exceed `n`, and this actually establishes `j = n / i`.

There is a little adjustment to perform when `i` is incremented: `i` becoming `i + 1` makes `p = i * j` become `(i + 1) * j = p + j`, and `p` may become too large. This is fixed by decrementing `j` as many times as necessary (`j--, p-= i`) to compensate.

Comment: Though I accepted the answer that mindriot submitted, I'd like you to know that your answer, especially the last paragraph, played a key role in the development of my understanding of the method. Thanks!

Comment: @kevin: Cheers. I recomend "A Method of Programming by Edsger W. Dijkstra, W. H. J. Feijen, Joke Sterringa"